# Microsoft word 2013 - if statement not working

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, field-codes

I have a field code with a strange behavior. When I put the code,

```
{ IF NUMPAGES=NUMPAGES "A" "B" }
```

I get `A` as expected however, when I reverse this, ie

```
{ IF NUMPAGES<>NUMPAGES "A" "B" }
```

I still get `A`.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to say

```
{ IF NUMPAGES <> NUMPAGES "A" "B" }
```

Word Help: [Field codes: IF field](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Field-codes-IF-field-9f79e82f-e53b-4ff5-9d2c-ae3b22b7eb5e) says,

> **Operator**
>
> Comparison operator.  Insert a space before and after the operator.
>                           ⋮

I can't find this documented anywhere, but it looks like Word is interpreting your code as

```
IF "NUMPAGES<>NUMPAGES" ≠ "" ...
```

Comment: Just as a followup, it needs to have braces around `NUMPAGES`, ie `{ IF { NUMPAGES } <> { NUMPAGES } "A" "B" }`